# User cash on delivery in django-oscar

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

I'm working in e-shop project using `django-oscar` and i trying to add COD support. I'm using [`django-oscar-cash-on-delivery`](https://github.com/michaelkuty/django-oscar-cash-on-delivery).

I did the [steps](https://github.com/michaelkuty/django-oscar-cash-on-delivery/blob/master/README.rst), you can see my configuration:

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'jet.dashboard',
    'jet',

    'axes',
    'cashondelivery',
    'django_extensions',
    'oscarapi',
    'paypal',
    'payu',
    'rest_framework',
    'robots',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'webpack_loader',
]
```

And created an app called `apps` and loaded properly:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = THIRD_PARTY_APPS + PROJECT_APPS + [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
] + get_core_apps(
    [
        'apps.shipping'
    ]
)
```

In `apps`folder i created an `apps.py` file with this code inside:

```
from oscar.app import Shop

# from apps.checkout.app import application as checkout_app
from cashondelivery.app import application as checkout_app


class ApplicationShop(Shop):
    checkout_app = checkout_app


application = ApplicationShop()
```

But i can't understand why Oscar doesn't show me the checkout template with cash on delivery method.

This is my structure folder:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways for integrate cash on delivery in `django-oscar` project:

1. Override checkout application:
   In this case is necessary override checkout templates because by default `Oscar` don't or can't get the `cashondelivery` checkout templates, at least `payment_details`. So, first you need override these template file and after create an app and inside it add a `app.py` file where you override the checkout application as `cashondelivery` [documentation](https://github.com/michaelkuty/django-oscar-cash-on-delivery/blob/master/README.rst) says.

   [image]
2. Create a custom view and checkout app:
   You can see in `django-oscar-paypal` integration package a sandbox example for integrate `paypal` with `Oscar`.
   You can see in this package that they use a checkout app for replace the defaul checkout app; inside this app they override `view.py` file and `app.view` file; override templates and override `app.py` file.

So, we can do the same for `django-oscar-cash-on-delivery`, so:
a. Create a new application called `checkout` inside the `apps` application if you want, or some like you. This application only will contain the views and application file.[image]

b. In views file we'll put the `cash-on-delivery` [views](https://github.com/michaelkuty/django-oscar-cash-on-delivery/blob/master/sandbox/apps/checkout/views.py) file, now it is in sanbox folder.

c. In app file inside checkout we declarate the checkout application:

```
from oscar.apps.checkout import app
from .views import PaymentDetailsView

class CheckoutApplication(app.CheckoutApplication):
    payment_details_view = PaymentDetailsView

application = CheckoutApplication()
```

d. Finally, we declarate our checkout app as default checkout app as [documentation](https://github.com/michaelkuty/django-oscar-cash-on-delivery/blob/master/README.rst) says.
e. We have ensure that the application override default check out application, in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = + get_core_apps(
    [
        'apps.checkout',
        'apps.shipping'
    ]
)
```

You can now pay with cash on delivery method in your Oscar project.
We recommend use the second way because enable you use more than one method for payment.

**PD:**
Wich the new master version we have moved the `views.py` file at sandbox folder, so, the first option won't work anymore. But, if you want it come back, say us please!